# This old fictional building

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This old fictional building

> Has its front at the very back
>
> Has its back at the very front
>
> And it ends in the middle!
>
> Peaceful at the entry, I would say

Can you name it?

Hint

> Five letter word. Front and back refers to the front and back of the
>  word

Comment: Fishing for a clue here a little bit but: are we talking about an old fiction that describes this building; or is the building its self old in the context of a relatively modern fiction; or is this an old fiction about a building from a similar age/time-period?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the hint, the answer must be

> The Castle of Zenda (where the fictional Prisoner of Zenda was imprisoned).

Because

> The front of the word "Zenda", Z, is at the back of the alphabet, and the back of the word, A, is at the front. The middle is the word "end". The "entry" of the word is Zen, a peaceful word.

Comment: Peaceful at the entry ZEN

Answer (score 2):

A guess at an old fictional building that ends in the middle:

> The Labyrinth - but I can't think of or find any reference to the other clues.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the intended answer, but I recon a

> Stargate, or any fictional Einstein–Rosen bridge (with a peaceful entrance), if you consider a 'gate' to be a building (stretch!).

would work, owing to

> the visibly flat nature of the gateway putting the front and back together, and the *end* would be both between (in the middle of) either side of the portal while also *somewhere else in space-time*.

Answer (score 0):

Why do i think of

> mostly every tomb in an adventure film/game?

I came to that because:

> The hero always goes the long way, when entrancing in front
>  Mostly everyone escape through a back door that's so quick to reach
>  It comes always down to the tomb in the 'middle' of the building
>  Peaceful and unknown is the entrance

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of:

> The Taj Mahal

Because:

> The front of the building is at the back of the gardens.
>  When most people see it, their backs are facing the very front of the garden.
>  The building is in fact a tomb, so it "ends" life in the middle.
>  The gardens at the entrance are very peaceful.

Comment: Not fictional, though :)

Comment: @jafe bollocks.